# Pass button text to command as arg with tkinter button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want some kind of button so that, when I press it, it will run a function with it's own text, so if the button says "hi there" then when clicked, it'll run `someFunction("hi there")`. I will be dynamically generating a list of buttons, with different text, based on a list of directories in another folder.
Below is my attempt at it.

```
import tkinter as tk
for folder in os.listdir("Servers"):
    btns.append(
        tk.Button(
            master,
            text=folder,
            command=lambda: handleButton(<the text of this button>)
        )
    )
```

Since I'm iterating, I can't just pass `folder` because it dynamically retrieves it and always uses the last name generated as an arg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use default value of argument on the lambda:

```py
for folder in os.listdir("Servers"):
    btns.append(
        tk.Button(
            master,
            text=folder,
            command=lambda f=folder: handleButton(f)
        )
    )
```